# Search in Mongo DB

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have to search the content of this JSON of the mongoDB, a value within metadata->ds_id

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58ff931630393501d6bb9f90"),
    "bachelor_degree" : "Médica",    
    "university" : "Universidad de Buenos Aires",
    "metadata" : {
        "graph_id" : "58FF931630393501D6FEA8C9",
        "entity_id" : "26",
        "ds_id" : "58FE3DC7303935698442B7A6" 
    },
    "actual_position" : "-",
    "city" : "Argentina - Buenos Aires"
}
```

I am using ROBO 3T. Would you help me in the consultation?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query for a specific ID value on the metadata.ds_id field like this:

```
> db.collection.find({ "metadata.ds_id": "58FE3DC7303935698442B7A6" })
```